# How to properly prevent multiple instances of my AutoHotKey script from running at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I have made this AutoHotKey script after reading the manual, searching and troubleshooting for endless hours in the last few weeks:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance force

if A_Args[1] > 0
{
    Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\blablabla\new notifications.png
}
else
{
    Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\blablabla\no new notifications.png
}
```

This, I have compiled into `test.exe`. Then I call it like this from a terminal: `test.exe 1`, `test.exe 0`, `test.exe 2`, `test.exe 3`, etc.

If I do it slowly/manually, it works: it only ever keeps one instance of the script, showing visually as a nice little icon in the Notification area (as intended), never launching multiple instances.

However, when I started actually using it for real, by calling the same terminal command from my scripts, it often opens two or more instances, which are kept open and just make the Notification area longer and longer, ignoring the rule that it only can run as one instance ever.

I was able to "solve" it by introducing a short "sleep" in my script after each such command call, so that the same script never calls it too quickly in succession. **However**, today, I realized that multiple *different* scripts of mine often call it at the same time, or nearly at the same time. This means that my "clever" solution of sleeping falls short.

I then thought that I can use the database to keep track of when the last time a script called this, and don't do it if it's too soon, but if I did that, the whole point would be lost since I can no longer trust the icon to accurately tell me whether or not there are new notifications in my system. I'd constantly be wondering if there had been such a "race condition" and manually go and check anyway, defeating the point of this visual indication which is supposed to let me always know "at a glance" whether or not there are new notifications in my system.

Maybe I could have a loop in my scripts and repeatedly re-try if it detects that a notification has been sent too recently, but that means my scripts will potentially stall for a long time as they all send notifications (especially in the morning, when I wake up and kickstart my system). It just seems like the wrong solution.

Is there really no way to properly handle this in the script itself? As is obvious from my description, the `#Persistent` and `#SingleInstance force` rules aren't respected.

(I've had similar problems in the past with programs being unable to "handle" running commands too quickly, and I never know what to do about it except to introduce sleep. But even then, it often glitches out. For example, Notepad++ requires me to first open a document and then open it again with a specified line number, sleeping in between, or else it doesn't go to the specified line.)

Comment: Just throwing ideas here `#Persistent` and `#SingleInstance force` might clash (and `#Persistent` makes it single instance anyway).  And have you tried `#SingleInstance ignore` which prevents the start of a new instance instead of forcing the replace of the old instance.

Comment: @ippi Well, I tried your suggestion, but with `#SingleInstance ignore`, it never replaces the old icon, so it only works the first time and all subsequent calls have no effect.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but have you tried RunWait to call test.exe in your scripts?

Comment: @RobertMiller You are not missing anything, but I clearly am. "RunWait" is apparently an AHK command, but what exactly do you mean that I should do with it?

Comment: If you have a line in your main ahk script  that is: test.exe n, you could replace it with RunWait test.exe n. Your script will then stop until  test.exe executes. That may or may not be acceptable for you, but it should prevent multiple  copies of test.exe.

Comment: @RobertMiller I guess my point is that I *don't* have such a line in my script?

Comment: OK. Obviously, i don't have a clear idea of what you are doing. Cheers.

Comment: @RobertMiller Is my description unclear in some way?

Comment: I think you just have one script running at a time, and then pass messages into that script which would tell the script to act accordingly. Making use of sending messages to the WindowProc is a pretty easy way since it's all implemented for you in AHK already. There's an example about it [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm#SendString) in the docs. It's a bit overly complicated for your use, since it's for sending *any string*. You could do with a much simpler data structure, but assuming it's over you head, can just copy paste the code there and it'll work as well.

Comment: You may see multiple icons in the system tray but it might not mean multiple instances are running but just that the systray icon stack did not refresh.